# C string as template non-type parameter works in gcc 6.3 but does not work in Visual Studio 2017 (19.16.27027.1 for x64)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

The following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<const char* Pattern> void f() {
    std::cout << Pattern << "\n";
}

static constexpr const char hello[] = "Hello";

int main() {
    f<hello>(); //Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27027.1 for x64
    //  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
    //
    //  string-as-template-parameter.cpp
    //  string-as-template-parameter.cpp(10): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
    //  (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1518)
    //   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
    //  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
    return 0;
}
```

works when compiled by gcc (g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516) but results in C1001 when compiled by VS 2017.

As a workaround I use:

```
#include <iostream>

template<const char** Pattern> void f() {
    std::cout << *Pattern << "\n";
}

static const char* hello = "Hello";

int main() {
    f<&hello>();
    return 0;
}
```

Does anybody have idea of more beautiful solution? May be initial code has an error which is skipped by gcc?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::string`?

Comment: are you really instantiating based on the string or on the pointer? For the workaround I am almost certain that it is the second. It matters, because "hello" is not necessarily the same as "hello".

Comment: This is the first time I see such template syntax of `template<Type var>`... What is good about it?

Comment: @Emadpres it is non-type template parameters. You can look for the classical factorial via templates example, you can find lots detailed discussions of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does anybody have idea of more beautiful solution?

You can use a reference to `std::string` instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<std::string & Pattern> void f() {
    std::cout << Pattern << "\n";
}

static std::string hello = "Hello";

int main() {
    f<hello>(); 
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles with [MSVC in Visual Studio](https://godbolt.org/z/SwLC4v).

This works because as per [Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter),  a named lvalue reference with linkage  is allowed as a non-type parameter. (Note that `hello` is not local.)

Comment: Whoa, non-type template arguments no longer need to be constant expressions in C++17? I swear, I look away *for one second* and the whole language has changed.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You can only pass global/static variables this way, and only to reference parameters. (Which makes sense, since you're effectively passing an address, and a variable has a single fixed address if it's static/global.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, I read the section in cppreference.com. Nevertheless this is a *huge* divergence from the previous behaviour, even though it makes sense if you think about it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, why do you think that hello is non-constant expression (when substitutet as a reference)? At least static constexpr std::string* s = &hello; works

Comment: @P.W: Even `const std::string`

Comment: @P.W, it's good idea, but in unknown reason it doesn't work for gcc 6.3. It's strange because for pointer to std::string gcc 6.3 works well. The problem for gcc is in hello literal - it doesn't consider it as a constant expression even in *&hello form

Comment: @oleg: For this to work in GCC 6.3, you have to specify `-std=c++17` option as it is not the default. See: https://godbolt.org/z/cUTIxA

Comment: @Jarod42: `const std::string` does not work with MSVC

Comment: @oleg Because according to the C++14 standard it simply isn’t (and I think it *still* isn’t, but I’m not entirely sure).

Comment: @oleg: Does this answer your question?